# SQL query help, conditional join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

SQL newbie here :)

Here are my tables if anyone's interested.

*AHH, cant post image yet*
http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/442/72098588.jpg

What I'm trying to do is query the tblPatientStats table within a date interval (@StartDate, @EndDate)
and group them accordingly in a data grid on winforms.

**So each row in tblPatientStats either have a RefDoctor or RefMode or both or none at all.**

So the query should return a table with the Name of the patient from tblPatient, the RefMode from tblRefMode, the Name of the RefDoctor (Title + FirstName + lastName) and SessionDate from tblPatientStats

==> yfrog dot com/0yhi2dj

Here is my attempt so far.

```
INSERT @Final(Name, Doctor, Mode, SessionDate)
 SELECT DISTINCT (FirstNames + LastName) as Name, 
 (tblRefDoctor.RefDTitle + ' ' + tblRefDoctor.RefDFNames + ' ' + tblRefDoctor.RefDName) AS Doctor, 
 tblRefMode.RefMode AS Mode, SessionDate 

 FROM tblPatientStats, tblPatient
 left outer join tblRefDoctor on (RefDoctor = tblRefDoctor.RefDoctor)
 left outer join tblRefMode on (RefModeID = tblRefMode.RefModeID)
 WHERE
 tblPatientStats.RefDoctor IS NOT NULL or tblPatientStats.RefModeID IS NOT NULL
 AND 
 tblPatient.PatientID = tblPatientStats.PatientID
 AND tblPatientStats.SessionDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

What am I doing wrong? The query times out every single time, the tables are small, less than 10K records each.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is because of the cartesian join on

```
tblPatientStats, tblPatient
```

Whilst there is a join condition in the `where` clause there is an issue with the precedence of the boolean operators. This is in order `Not, And, Or` so I think you need brackets around the 'Or' ed conditions.

The `WHERE` condition on the original query with brackets applied to show the effective operator precedence is

```
 WHERE
 tblPatientStats.RefDoctor IS NOT NULL or 

(tblPatientStats.RefModeID IS NOT NULL 
     AND tblPatient.PatientID = tblPatientStats.PatientID  
     AND tblPatientStats.SessionDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

This is almost certainly not the desired semantics and will likely bring back too many rows.

I've moved the join condition between `tblPatientStats` and `tblPatient` up into the JOIN clauses and added brackets to the `Or` ed conditions.

```
 FROM tblPatientStats
 inner join tblPatient on tblPatient.PatientID = tblPatientStats.PatientID
 left outer join tblRefDoctor on RefDoctor = tblRefDoctor.RefDoctor
 left outer join tblRefMode on RefModeID = tblRefMode.RefModeID
 WHERE
 (tblPatientStats.RefDoctor IS NOT NULL or tblPatientStats.RefModeID IS NOT NULL)
 AND tblPatientStats.SessionDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Yet another reason why you should not use implied syntax or combined implied with explicit.